# getting a variable into a bash script into a python script

Tags: bash, arguments, alias

I have a python script I want to use for navigation. it returns a directory path 
ex /user/bin/dir/
I am making an ailas to it but I cant seem to pass it variables

this works in a shell

```
> cd `python ~doug/scripts/nv.py arg1
>>/user/bin/dir/
```

alias nav='cd `python ~doug/scripts/nv.py $1`'
but this alias doesn't work

I would expect arg1 gets passed to $1

Comment: err cd `python ~doug/scripts/nv.py arg1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bash` aliases cannot take parameters; you want to use a shell function instead:

```
nav () {
    cd $(python ~doug/scripts/nv.py $1)
}
```

Comment: Depending on the script, you might want `cd "$(python ~doug/scripts/nv.py "$@")"` to pass all arguments instead of just the first, and also avoid trouble if the script outputs paths with spaces or glob characters.